# I am working on CodeIgniter, but unable to output entity that has timestamp at mysql end but other entities are working(coming out well)

Tags: codeigniter

### /// my controller has this :

```
       $users = $this->LoginModel->getAllUser();        
       $data["users"] = $users;        
       $this->load->view("login/allusers",$data);
```

### /// my view has this :

```
    foreach($users as $user){
            echo "username : ".$user->getUsername()." Time :   ".$user->getTimepost()."<br>";
            }
```

Question is that only : `$user->getTimepost()` is generating error during echo

Comment: Can you give us your getAllUser(); model code?

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: getTimepost() is funcation name or Table COLUMNS

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small code that you can use hopefully it will help you.

**CONTROLLER**

```
function viewallusers()
{
    $data['users'] = $this->Loginmodel->getAllUsers();
    $this->load->view('login/allusers',$data);
}
```

**MODEL**

```
function getAllUsers()
{
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tblName');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
}
```

**VIEW**

```
foreach($users as $u)
{
  echo "username : ".$u->user_name;
  echo " Time :   ".$user->time_stamp;
  echo "<br>";
}
```

**WHERE user_name AND time_stamp ARE YOUR TABLE COLUMNS. using the model i have given, it gives back an OBJECT TYPE of what you got from the database. and can be accessible using FOREACH USING THE ARROW.**

The syntax is as follows:

```
$u->YOUR_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME_YOU_WANT_TO_GET
```

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate